# How can I create a Java device emulator

Tags: java, java-me, cdc

I want to create my own device to be compatible with the Java ME SDK, in fact it is a CDC PBP1.0 device.

Does anyone have any experience to share on this or can point me to the correct place within Sun's jumbled website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog by Sun explains it all http://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/how_to_create_a_custom should get you started pretty well.

Comment: This is more of what I had in mind, the problem is apart from this little blog entry there isn't any decent documentation.  So I have created my own device configuration, but it fails with no useful logging and don't know where to start due to no documentation
.

Comment: There are docs, they just aren't orginised very well, If you look at the javadocs for the emulator code its self you can kinda work out what properties are used where. Yes I agree this isn't ideal but well j2me has and seems it will always be a lack of documentation.

Answer (score 5):

[PhoneME Advanced](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Mobileandembedded/PhoneMEAdvanced) is Sun's open source CDC implementation.

If you want to create your own clean room implementation of CDC, you can read the [CDC specifications](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=36) but licensing the Test Conformance Kit to prove you are CDC-compliant will cost you money.

You can also look into [microemulator](http://www.microemu.org/).